# Filtering Pulling from list sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have this file that filters based on values from another page. My question is there a way to ignore a field if there is no value in the List Column?

Right now an error happens if all the list values are not filled out. List values are the Criteria_C etc in the photo.

Thanks

Also how do I get it show more than one result?

```
Sub Proto()


Dim cList As Variant
Dim ccList As Variant
Dim uList As Variant
Dim towList As Variant
Dim aList As Variant
Dim pmList As Variant

Dim wsP As Worksheet
Dim wsL As Worksheet
Dim rng_C As Range
Dim rng_CC As Range
Dim rng_U As Range
Dim rng_ToW As Range
Dim rng_A As Range
Dim rng_PM As Range
Dim rng_Projects As Range

Set wsP = Worksheets("Projects")
Set wsL = Worksheets("Lists")
Set rng_Projects = wsP.Range("$B$6").CurrentRegion

Set rng_C = wsL.Range("List_C")
Set rng_CC = wsL.Range("List_CC")
Set rng_U = wsL.Range("List_U")
Set rng_ToW = wsL.Range("List_ToW")
Set rng_A = wsL.Range("List_A")
Set rng_PM = wsL.Range("List_PM")

cList = rng_C.Value
ccList = rng_CC.Value
uList = rng_U.Value
towList = rng_ToW.Value
aList = rng_A.Value
pmList = rng_PM.Value

rng_Projects.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(cList)
rng_Projects.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(ccList)
rng_Projects.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(uList)
rng_Projects.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(towList)
rng_Projects.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(aList)
rng_Projects.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(pmList), Operator _
    :=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether or not the array has values in it or not before you set it as the filter. For example if you want to skip over "Criteria_C" if it doesn't have any values, you can use the following code:

```
If Not IsEmpty(cList) Then rng_Projects.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
                              Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(cList)
```

Your code should also show multiple results if you have data in your table that matches all the filter criteria you indicate. If you want to use multiple criteria (say "FEMA" and "AU" for example), you'll have to expand the "List_C" range before the macro executes.

Comment: Its seeming to give me errors. So would this replace rng_Projects.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(cList)?

Comment: yes this line of code replaces `rng_Projects.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(cList)`. What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: Also this is highlighted 'Set rng_C = wsL.Range("List_C")'

Comment: Then just to test it I commented out various  rng_Projects.AutoFilter's and it worked in not needing any of the criteria that was commented out.

Comment: OK. My assumption was that the various criteria that you enter into your first screenshot were all named ranges. That way, if any of them were empty, the if statement that I originally shared would skip over that filter

Comment: =Lists!$F$1 = Head_C...... and  =OFFSET(Lists!Head_A,1,0,COUNTA(Lists!$F:$F)-1,1) = List_C That's the range naming I have

Comment: If I set rng_C = wsL.Range("Test_C"), where Test_C =Lists!$B$2:$B$2. It works. Thanks

Comment: This got me thinking though. Could I use something like If Not (cList) = "All" For the same effect?

Comment: If your `cList` remains a Range that only has one cell, then yes, you can do that as well. That would exclude any criteria from the filter for which the user types "All". So, all together you can do `If Not (IsEmpty(cList) Or (cList) = "All") Then`...

Comment: Is it possible o sort on multiple criteria?

Comment: your ranges (where you enter your criteria) would need to be expanded to more than one cell.